# php mail Cc not sending email if left blank

Tags: php

I am not sure if anyone can help me with this issues but I currently have a php mailing form. everything works great, I am trying to setup Cc options.

code.

```
$subject = "Name #$name_id test data";
$mailer ='Company <Support@company.com>';
$headers = "From: $mailer \r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: $cc \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($mailer) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body style="background:#eeeeee">';

mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

cc var is $cc=$VAR["cc_user"];  which is linked to html form. so here is I enter an email address in the html input form and submit, it works. if I leave blank, email does not send. can anyone help me with this.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Show your full code; it's way too vague.

Comment: it's too much data to post here as I have html for email type. however, I've updated the info above

Comment: I need to know how `$VAR` is defined as well as `$cc`. Are you using some type of function?

Comment: $cc is   $cc=$VAR["cc_user"];

Comment: I know that, but `$VAR` is not a PHP core value. You may have meant to use `$cc=$_POST["cc_user"];` --- Again, there's not enough code for me to help you any further.

Comment: it send email fine to the cc address when add in html input field. but if I leave the input field blank without entering an email address. it does not send. that is my problem. also keep in mind, when cc email is added it sends to both email, cc and support@company.com

Answer (score 0):

Fixed..

```
$emailto= $sql['CUSTOMER_EMAIL'].", ".$VAR["cc_user"];
```